# how do I resize a UIView after orientation change (code includes doesn't seem to work)

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

Why doesn't this UIView layout code work as I want?

Background:

- I have a custom UIView I have in my UIViewController
- The custom UIView has a clock background imageview and an hourhand imageview
- After introducing some code (see below) to try to resize the hour hand for an orientation change I'm getting stuck.
- The code below really stuffs things up - the border outlike of the hour glass hand is way off with this code

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong - there's obvious some assumption or misunderstanding I have for it to screw up like this...

Code called by UIViewController (in "didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation" method) to my custom view:

```
// Centre image 
self.hourHandImageView.center = self.hourFaceUIImageView.center;

// Resize to cater for either Portrait or Landscape orientation
CGSize currSize = self.hourFaceUIImageView.frame.size;
float newHourHandImageheightWidth = currSize.width < currSize.height ? currSize.width : currSize.height;
CGSize newHourHandViewSize = CGSizeMake(newHourHandImageheightWidth, newHourHandImageheightWidth);
CGRect newRect = self.hourHandImageView.frame;
newRect.size = newHourHandViewSize;
self.hourHandImageView.frame = newRect;
```

PS.  Without the "Resize to cater for either Portrait or Landscape orientation" code the hour hand correctly stays centered where it should (noting I use transformation to turn it around).  There all I really need to do is resize the hour hand appropriately after an orientation change, noting the hour background image is smaller in the landscape mode.

Comment: Are the changes in dimensions are getting reflected? Is the anchor point is coming in wrong place?

Comment: did you try [self.view layoutSubviews] or [self.view setNeedsDisplay] ? try setNeedsDisplay to refresh the view. call the method in the last after you change frame

Comment: @Ravin - the center is coming up in the wrong place, and size is incorrect

Comment: @Rahul - just tried this and it doesn't seem to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, how can you tell if you are in portrait or landscape orientation? With this (?):

```
float newHourHandImageheightWidth = currSize.width < currSize.height ? currSize.width : currSize.height;
```

What i would advice you, is to do something like this:

-

```
(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
        [self reOrderToPortrait];
    } else if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)){
        [self reOrderToLandScape];
    }
}
```

Then on each method, you should define the new frames for your views. Start by removing your autosizing from your views, because you will define the new frames, and you dont want that to interfere with. You could also define some mesures like this:

```
#define hourHandImageViewPortrait CGPointMake(...,...)
#define hourHandImageViewLandScape CGPointMake(..., ...)
```

Comment: thanks for the tips - I think that's overall what I'm trying to do in my code, i.e. reset via use of allocating a new Rect.  Don't suppose you can see what's wrong with the approach I'm doing however?  I have a feeling I could use your tips but I may end up with the same issue in the manner I'm creating/allocating the new frame....  :(

Comment: Your aproach is wrong at first glance by two reasons: 1) You are trying to figure it out if you are in portrait or landscape mode by comparing the width with height. 2) Even tho you want to make use of autosize of your views, you are still trying, after that, change their frames. In my opinion, its kinda rocket science...